# halcyon.MVC is not working in the .net 6 and throwing System.TypeLoadException issue:

Tags: .net-6.0

Halcyon.mvc is not working in the .net 6 and throwing following System.TypeLoadException:

```
System.TypeLoadException: 'Could not load type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Formatters.JsonSerializerSettingsProvider' from assembly 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Formatters.Json, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60'.'
```

**On the below code:**

```
c.OutputFormatters.Add(new JsonHalOutputFormatter(
    halJsonMediaTypes: new string[] {
       ApplicationMediaType.HALPlusJson,
       ApplicationMediaType.HALPlusJsonVendor,
       ApplicationMediaType.HALPlusJsonVendorV1
    }));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please find the below link for the upgraded DLL https://github.com/click2kabilan/halcyon